# How to persist data from swarm services?

Tags: jenkins, docker-swarm

I have databases hosted on docker swarm and linked it to jenkins.
So that whenever user runs a jenkins job a container will be created with the build number appended to the name and the user can use the database for his testing.

[image: containers]

Once his testing is completed, he can run the jenkins job again and can use the option to delete the docker swarm service.

So far well and good. But whenever the server restarts or with any other issue, new container will be created for the service and all the data created in the database will lost.

Is there anyway to persist the data so that new container also uses the old one.
Attaching a volume in swarm mode to try but if multiple services will be created with same command and and it would tag to same volume.

Comment: I assume it's a multi node cluster. With Swarm, a service will create a task on whichever node it sees fit, which again will create the container. Since a container can be spawned on any node, you will need to use volumes backed by a shared storage. The build-in local driver supports nfs (v4!) and cifs - never had any problems with nfs v4 in the past, not even with databases. If you are looking for an entirely different storage type, take a look at the list of volume plugins and check if your desired target storage is supported, e.g. Ceph.

Comment: Ok, you mean to say, apply volumes with shared locations. But how will we manage multiple copies of same service.Like in a jenkins job, whenever user runs that it creates a copy of new service with buildnumber at the end. How will we manage the drive there?

Comment: I wrote about what's necessary to have make volumes accessible in a cluster - regeardless of jenkins. Your use-case is still not clear enough for me to make any recommendations. Though, one thing is sure: this will be a pita to implement in a jenkins job.

Comment: May be it's a Pita, but it is the option I thought to provide users an UI option for creating a service. If it is that scrap, please suggest a different option.